# How to implement admob banner ads to 2nd activity top of a scrollview?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a new app that has 2 activities. 1st is listview and 2nd is scrollview through listview items. I have successfully placed a banner in my first activity and trying to put the second banner in scrollview but I can't.
Below is the java file of my second activity that is a scrollview and I want to put a banner ad at the top of scrollview.
please help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "MyAppID");

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MyAdUnit");

    adView= findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    TextView mDetailTv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");
    String mContext = intent.getStringExtra("contentTv");

    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);
    mDetailTv.setText(mContext);
}
```

}

Comment: can you attach your activity_new.xml file?

Comment: I tried but I can't, btw my problem has been solved.